# Universal Links in Managed Mode

Tags: ios, mdm, ios-universal-links, device-management

I am trying to implement Universal Links (https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) feature for my iOS app. The app is only available to the people who have company's managed iOS devices and the app is distributed through company's MDM to them. The domain that links to the app is the company's internal network and only accessible through managed devices. Everything has been working as expected so far. That's to the extent that I have put the proper JSON file at for example https://myprivatenetwork.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association and I have tested the iOS app with `mode=developer` successfully by adding `applinks:myprivatenetwork.com?mode=developer` under Associated Domains as it is mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains

But when I change the domain to `applinks:myprivatenetwork.com?mode=managed` and distribute the app through MDM to the company users, the Universal Links don't work. Here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains there is a mention of

> `managed`
> Specifies that only devices managed with a mobile device management (MDM) profile can access the domain. This mode requires consent from the MDM administrator."

But there is no details on how to get consent from the MDM administrator.

There is also minute 18 of this video that talks about this but does not go into details for the managed mode case: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10098/

If you know the missing part in this explanation, please let me know what it is. I know it must be related to some setting on the MDM side. But not sure what I need to communicate with the MDM team as what they need to do to give consent to this app and the associated domains.

**Update:**
I have so far found this which seems to suggest what the solution is. I yet have to coordinate with the MDM team to actually try it.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664481
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/installapplicationcommand/command/attributes?language=objc